# (Angular 5) Error: control.registerOnChange is not a function

Tags: angular, typescript, formarray

I need to show the values in a form to edit later. always show me this error "*ERROR Error: control.registerOnChange is not a function*"

I build my form in this way

```
 form = this._fb.group({
  createdAt:'',
  customer: this._fb.group({
    name: '',
    lastname: '',
    phone: '',
    address: ''
  }),
  purchases: this._fb.array([ <-- this is the problematic,the others work well
    this._fb.group({
      product: this._fb.group({
        name:'',
        location:'',
        categoryS:'',
        price:''
      }),
      quantity: ''
    })
  ])      
});
```

and try to show it

```
   <div formArrayName="purchases">
        <label>Products:</label> 
     <div *ngFor="let product of form.controls.purchases.controls; let i = index">
         <input [formControlName]="i" class="form-control"/>            
      </div>
     </div>
```

any ideas?

[***View in StackBlitz***](https://stackblitz.com/edit/invoice-stackoverflow-vlx8uc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can share my idea.

Change template as follows:

```
<div *ngFor="let product of form.controls.purchases.controls; let i = index" [formGroupName]="i">
  <div formGroupName="product">
    <input formControlName="name" class="form-control"/>  
    <input formControlName="location" class="form-control"/>     
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

And also make sure you correctly fill purchases array on edit action:

```
invoice.purchases.forEach(purchase => {
  purchasesFormArray.push(this._fb.group({
    product: this._fb.group(purchase.product),
    quantity: purchase.quantity
  }));
});
```

Check also forked **[Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/invoice-stackoverflow-vpqb9f?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcomponents%2Finvoice-list%2Finvoice-list.component.ts)**